# Get the number of inputs and outputs of MapReduce in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to get the number of inputs and outputs of the map phase and the reduce phase and the time of the complete map/reduce job with Java. These statistics are written on the terminal but I need to get it with a Java code and to write it on my own interface, just after the line:

```
job_blocking.waitForCompletion(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

After this line, you can get the number of MAP_INPUT_RECORDS and REDUCE_OUTPUT_RECORDS (also MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS), by getting the values of those counters:

```
long map_input_records = job.getCounters()
    .findCounter("org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Task$Counter","MAP_INPUT_RECORDS")
    .getValue();
long map_output_records = job.getCounters()
    .findCounter("org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Task$Counter","MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS")
    .getValue();
long reduce_input_records = job.getCounters()
    .findCounter("org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Task$Counter","REDUCE_INPUT_RECORDS")
    .getValue();
long reduce_output_records = job.getCounters()
    .findCounter("org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Task$Counter","REDUCE_OUTPUT_RECORDS")
    .getValue();
```

For the time needed to run the job, I don't know if there is another way (easier) than setting a long variable with the current time before and after it gets executed and getting their difference.